# mediawiki account creation with google only

Tags: php, mediawiki, wiki, google-signin

I am using media wiki version 1.30.0. I want people to create account through google login only i.e. I don't want people to manually create account by adding username and email but only through google login. Is it possible to do that?
( P.s. Is it possible to add google login in Request Account?).

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: code as in code in LocalSettings.php?

Comment: @JohnF. yes, please tell us what you've already tried. According to https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:GoogleLogin , enabling the extension and setting `$wgGroupPermissions['*']['createaccount'] = false;` should work.

Comment: That command line will remove createaccount for everybody. But I want people to create account with google login.

Comment: See [here](https://discourse-mediawiki.wmflabs.org/t/googlelogin-account-creation-via-special-userlogin/93?u=tgr) for a discussion of the current limitations of using third-party login providers.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable [GoogleLogin](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:GoogleLogin) and disable the normal registration provider in [`$wgAuthManagerAutoConfig`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgAuthManagerAutoConfig). The latter would be something like

```
unset( $wgAuthManagerAutoConfig['primaryauth'][MediaWiki\Auth\LocalPasswordPrimaryAuthenticationProvider::class] );
```

Comment: thanks man. It works. Can you provide me a link where I can read more about this?

Comment: The documentation on [SessionManager and AuthManager](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:SessionManager_and_AuthManager), it's not very accessible though. Also see my comment above.